# How to compare entered password in input login field with the md5 password stored in database?

Tags: php, md5

**UPDATE(solved): Previously I set the password length to 15 characters where it should be 32 character since the password is encrypted to md5. Now it works fine. Thanks for all the answers and suggestions.**

Below is the register php code. The code works fine and able to store password in the database in md5.

```
  <html>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1']);

    $enc_password = md5($password);

    if($name && $username && $password && $password1)
    {
        if(strlen($name)<30)
        {
            if(strlen($username)<10)
            {
                if(strlen($password)<15 || strlen($password)>6)
                {
                    if($password == $password1)
                    {
                        require "dbc.php";
                        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$name','$username','$enc_password')");     
                        echo "Registration Complete! <a href='index.php'>Click here to login</a>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Passwords must match";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Your password must be between 6 and 15 characters";   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Your username is too long";   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Your name is too long";
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "All fields are required"; 
    }
}

?>

    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo "$name"; ?>"> Max Length:30<p>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo "$username"; ?>"> Max Length:10<p>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"> Max length:15<p>
        Re-Enter Password: <input type="password" name="password1"><p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="<< Back to Login Area" onclick="window.location='../login%20and%20registration/members.php'">

</html>
```

Below is the login php code.

```
    <?php

session_start();

require "dbc.php";

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$enc_password = md5($password);

if($username&&$password)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrow!=0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $db_username = $row['username'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];
    }

    if($username==$db_username&&$password==$db_password)
    {
        //echo "Logged in <a href='members.php'>Click here to enter the members area</a>";
        $_SESSION['username']=$db_username;
        header("location: members.php");
    }
    else 
    {
        header("location: index.php?error=Incorrect Password");
    }
}
else 
{
    header("location: index.php?error=That user doesn't exist");
}
}

else 
{
    header("location: index.php?error=All fields are required");
}

?>
```

The problem is I kept getting  the "Incorrect Password" when I try to log in. I think theres something with retrieving the password from the database. Anyone can help?

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use MD5 for password hashing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/401684/1607098)

Comment: Since the database contains the MD5 password, your comparison needs to be with `$enc_password` instead of `$password`, i.e. `if($username==$db_username&&$enc_password==$db_password)`

Comment: If you're storing password hashes (which you ought to, but they ought to be salted), there's no *need* to impose a maximum length on the password - if the user wants to use the entire text of War and Peace, let them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$enc_password` instead of `$password` in line:

```
if($username==$db_username&&$password==$db_password)
```

P.S. Also if you use md5 then don't do `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `md5` will change your string and all injects will be removed.

P.P.S. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_*`

**UPDATE**

Also username must be **case insensitive** so better to do:

```
if(strcasecmp($username, $db_username)===0 && $password==$db_password)
```

[strcasecmp](http://php.net/strcasecmp)

Comment: ive changed from if($username==$db_username&&$password==$db_password) to if($username==$db_username&&$enc_password==$db_password) still give the same error

Comment: Then make `die($username.'=='.$db_username.'&&'.$enc_password.'=='.$db_password);` and see what is different in output.

Comment: @user2251028 also see my update, you may have case problem with your username.

Comment: I tried die($username.'=='.$db_username.'&&'.$enc_password.'=='.$db_password); got this error message                                                        SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for                                          Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\wamp\www\login and registration\login.php on line 30

Comment: Probably you added it into if() and else statements. Move that code before if

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if($username==$db_username&&$password==$db_password)
```

to

```
if($username == $db_username && $enc_password == $db_password)
```

You are using `$password` but it should be `$enc_password`

Answer (score 0):

you're comparing $password with $db_password while you should be comparing $enc_password with $db_password.

```
if($username==$db_username&&$enc_password==$db_password)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should compare like this

```
 $password = md5($password);//change value entered of password to md5

 if($username==$db_username&&$password==$db_password)
```

Comment: try this if(($username==$db_username)&&($password==$db_password))